Testing whether mean sample difference between two groups is different in two different samples
Suppose in a medical study there are the following students recruited to the study:
300 Japanese males, 500 Japanese females
600 Australian males, 700 Australian females
The particular study is about if height difference between gender is more pronounced in countries with certain socio-economic institutional structure
We do a unpaired t-test for the Japanese students, say the height difference between gender is 3cm
We do a unpaired t-test for the Australian students, say the height difference between gender is 1.5cm
How can we test if the Japanese gender height difference is more pronounced than that in Australia? Which statistical test would be suitable for this purpose, if you don't mind showing me the exact step-by-step calculations?
